# How to calculate elasticsearch index size?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I have time-based indices(log-nginx-2021.01.28) from 26th December 2020 to jan 28th January 2021 each index size is around 4.5 mb and these indices have 3 primary and 1 replica shard total 6 shards so my question is the index size 4.5 mb including replica also?

Answer (score 4):

you can use the `_cat/indices?v` API, which prints the total index size and total size of primary shards.

if you can provide the output of Above API which shows your index in question, we can confirm its a total index size or size of all primary shards.

[image: output of above API]