# What is the best approach for calculating index size

Tags: elasticsearch

I have 11 different index and each index have 60 indices

**index_name**

1. log-wlb-application
2. log-wlb-sysmon
3. log-wlb-wmiactivity
4. log-wlb-security
5. log-wlb-system
6. log-wlb-powershell
7. log-pb-dns
8. log-pb-flow
9. log-pb-http
10. log-pb-icmp
11. log-pb-tls

for example for one index i have these indices.

`log-wlb-application-2020.11.24 . . . . log-wlb-application-2021.01.24`

I have to calulate average index size of each index because it takes so much  time to calculate
Is it good approach to calulate average index size on weekly bases because on monthly bases it is time-consuming.

Comment: log-wlb-application is a index name or alias name??

Comment: logstash daily create new index like log-wlb-application-2020.11.24 log-wlb-sysmon-2020.11.24 etc and now i have 660 indices and each day i have 11 indicies created and since its been 60 days so i have 660 indices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure why you think it takes so much time to calculate the index size, you can simply use the `_cat/indecs?v` API and even can filter by your index prefix like if you want to know all the indices and size of indices starting with `log-wlb-application` , you can use the `_cat/indices/log-wlb-application*?v` which will print you all the indices starting with `log-wlb-application` and their size as explained in my previous answer to your [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65942751/how-to-calculate-elasticsearch-index-size) SO question.

Above `_cat/indices` API is super fast and you can call it programatically and automate the calculating the size of all your indices on a daily basis.